# How do i send information through a segue in swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, tableview, segue

I am trying to send text from one ViewController to the next and I cant get any data to show on the receiving end. The data is coming from a table view with parsed data to a regular ViewController. The idLabel in the last function is what needs to be updated on the receiving end.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage

class ListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewProducts: UITableView!

    var ref:DatabaseReference?
    var databaseHandle: DatabaseHandle?

    var postData = [String]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ref = Database.database().reference()

        databaseHandle = ref?.child("0").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            let post = snapshot.value as? String

            if let actualPost = post {
            self.postData.append(actualPost)

            self.tableViewProducts.reloadData()



            }
        })
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(postData)
        return postData.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
        cell?.textLabel?.text = postData[indexPath.row]

        cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white


        return cell!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetails", sender: self)

        func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, for: Any?){

            if segue.destination is ProductViewController
            {
                let vc = segue.destination as? ProductViewController
                vc?.idLabel?.text = postData[indexPath.row]

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` needs to be a top level function in the ViewController, and note the signature is `sender` and not `for`.

Comment: There are many patterns to help with this. Creating a current selected type class and having everything that needs it see what it was last set to. Passing data between VC's. Using global variables (would prefer the first suggestion over this). Also, all of this has been answered many times before, what searches did you do that didn't help earlier?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to take the *func prepare* out of the tableView function and leverage the representedObject var.

Assuming the firstVC is segueing to the secondVC (a SecondViewController class) and you want to pass a string, it would look something like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let secondVC = segue.destinationController as! SecondController

    secondVC.representedObject = "some string"
}
```

in your second view controller;

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: NSTextField!

override func viewWillAppear() {

    self.textField.stringValue = self.representedObject as! String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are trying to update the UI before the view being presented in the code:

```
    vc?.idLabel.text = postData[indexPath.row]
```

You have several choices here, the most simple one is to create a variable on the secondViewController

```
    class SecondViewController {
        var someText: String!
        @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            idLabel.text = someText
        }
    }
```

Or you could add a delegate method and ditch the prepare(for segue:)

Example: https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/pass-data-with-delegation-in-swift-86f6bc5d0894